# How to change the width of lines generated with `\varline` in MusiXTeX?

Tags: line, musixtex

Does anybody know how to change the width of the line generated with the `\varline` command? The default width appears very thin in my document.

```
\begin{music}
\startextract%
\NOTEs%
\cu h\varline{3}{5\elemskip}{9}\cl k%
\en%
\zendextract%
\end{music}
```

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome. What is your complete code tex? Can you put it and not a fragment?

Answer (score 1):

Some analysis, no final solution yet.

`\varline` is defined in `musixtex.tex`, lines 5286 ff. As you can see, it uses a font, abbreviated by `mxsps`, on several occasions, where the snippet shows only two:

```
% varline #1=height[dimen] #2=length[dimen] #3=slope (1\eqiv 1.125degree)
% (comments and ideas from Ian Collier)              (from -20 upto 20 )
% This macro is used by some of the others which follow,
% using it directly it must be set in zero box

\def\varline#1#2#3{\n@v#3\y@i#2%
  \n@ii-\tw@nty \min@n@v\n@ii
  \max@n@v\tw@nty \n@iii\n@v
  \ifnum\n@v<\z@ \n@v-\n@v \advance\n@v\tw@nty \fi % offset to lower linechars
  \advance\n@v\@xxix
  \setbox\ch@box\hbox{\mxsps\char\n@v}%
  \y@iv\wd\ch@box \y@ii\qu@rt\p@ \y@ii\n@iii\y@ii \y@iii\z@
  \raise#1\internote\hbox{\ifx\@hook\@ne \mxsps\char\n@iv \fi
% main loop
...
```

This font is defined earlier in line 931 (depending on your editor)

```
% piano brackets, slides, guitar chords, lines, (de)crescendi, circles

\font\mxsps=musixspx
```

Font `musixspx` is installed in my environment in 3 directories under `...\MiKTeX2\fonts\...` .

Unfortunately I'm not experienced enough to see, if at all and how linewidth of `\varline` alone might be changed. But perhaps somebody else can indicate now.

**P.S.**: If anything fails you may send a request to the current curator of the [WIMA: Werner Icking Music Archive](https://icking-music-archive.org/index.php).